# Comparing Two C++ Vectors of different length when one holds lines and one holds letters, want to see what letters are in lines

Tags: c++, vector

Basically, im writing a program that is supposed to compare a char vector to a string vector made out of each line from a file, the `char vector` is supposed to iterate through the `string vector`.

when it finds a match it should spit out the line number and the offset of the character and save them as variables.

I've started on this but the way im doing it now I'm having a problem where if the message that needs to be encoded in the position of the characters contains more then one of the same letter, it only prints it once, and it also prints the characters out of order.

for example if the message was AGAIN A would only be printed once and the message thats left would be scrambled. Here is the way i've done it below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookVector.size(); i++) 
    for (int x = 0; x < bookVector[i].size(); x++) 
        if (find(messageVector.begin(), messageVector.end(), bookVector[i][x]) != messageVector.end()) 
        {
            cout << "found a match at "
                 << bookVector[i][x]
                 << " at positions "
                 << i << "," << x << endl;
        }
```

Comment: What does "the message thats left would be scrambled" mean? Please post a [mcve] with minimal (hardcoded) test input, expected result, and actual result.

Comment: Also, your search seems to be the reverse of what you're describing. (It's hard to tell what's correct because your question talks about "characters" and "lines", but your code about "book" and "message".)

Comment: im sorry for the confusion. the message is just a message split after each character into a separate element and the book is supposed to be used as the key to encode the letters, I can post a picture of the sample output, the message is supposed to be THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE. The output is this https://i.imgur.com/DH7lSF4.png
the book file im using is
ABCDE FG\n
HIJKLMNO\n
PQRSTUVWXYZ